# sys.argv got lost when using Dockerfile + pipenv + baker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, command-line-arguments, pipenv

Consider the following app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import baker

@baker.command
def initial_setup(setting1, setting2):
    # do some important prep work here

@baker.command
def start(arg1, arg2):
    # do your thing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    baker.run()
```

Here I am using [baker](https://pypi.org/project/Baker/) that exposes my functions as sub-commands.

I also have a docker file:

```
FROM alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV SHELL=/bin/ash

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add python3
RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv

RUN pipenv install
RUN pipenv run ./app.py initial_setup foo bar
CMD pipenv run ./app.py start baz qux
```

When I am running `docker build .` the initial_setup step fails with

```
Step ...: RUN pipenv run ./app.py initial_setup foo bar
[...]
No command specified
The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv run ./app.py initial_setup foo bar' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

When I am running `pipenv run ./app.py initial_setup foo bar` in my command line it works, but inside the Dockerfile build it seems that the `sys.argv` is not passed to baker.

Any idea how to convince the docker file to pass the arguments along to my app?

*Update:*

- I tried both moving the initial_setup command into a shell script, and using bash over ash, both to no avail.
- Added a steps omitted from my Dockerfile in response to [@stacksonstacks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6163736/stacksonstacks)'s comment.

Comment: You'll need to install python, pip OS packages and pipenv + baker pypi packages. e.g. `RUN apk add --no-cache python python-pip && pip install baker pipenv`

Comment: @stacksonstacks I *did* very similar thing to what you suggested, and I just omitted it from the OP, but your point is valid, so I put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `sys.argv` was passed as expected and that I have only my stupidity to blame:

I had a typo spelling `initial_setup`, and in such cases *baker* doesn't recognize the argument as a command, hence the error message "No command specified".